# Does Anyone know where this this code is throwing an error?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am getting this error from the following code. It's a simple insert query to a database from input form on site.

```
Error: INSERT INTO email_contacts (name1, email1, cType) VALUES (?, ?, 'buyer')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, 'buyer')' at line 1
```

Does anyone what might be causing this error?

I've used this same code on different sites and it worked just fine. Not sure if I am just overlooking something small or what.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

//database info
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myuser";
$password = "myPassword";
$db = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO email_contacts (name1, email1, cType) VALUES (?, ?, 'buyer')";
$stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$name,$email);
$stmt->execute();

if($conn -> query($sql) === TRUE){
    echo "SUCCESS";
}else{
    echo "Error: ".$sql . "<br>" . $conn ->error;
}
$conn ->close();
```

should insert into email_contacts table and echo "success"

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error is, sadly, a [*cargo cult code*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Although it happens to all of us when we just mindlessly copy-paste the code, but nevertheless, *we are supposed to understand what does our code do* and add operators consciously.

The error checking code you added,

```
if($conn -> query($sql) === TRUE){
```

is *trying to run your query again* (which makes no sense by itself) and without a prepared statement. And naturally, you get this error, as `query()` doesn't understand placeholders.

Ironically, a code to check for the error is the reason why you are getting the error.

But the most interesting part, testing the query result manually is wrong altogether, no matter whether its implementation is technically correct or not. Instead, **you must configure mysqli to throw an exception in case of error** automatically:

- it will make your code less bloated (as you won't have to add any such code at all)
- it will make your code *production-friendly* (as it's gross to have such an error blurted out on a live server)
- *incidentally, it will answer your very question* (in case of the real database error) - *where* your code is throwing an error. Your current code has, so to say, no "birth certificate", and in a large codebase it will be indeed impossible to find out in which part it failed - it could be any query, in any file. Whereas a properly thrown error always contains a file name and a line number, as well as a *stack trace* that shows the exact path your code execution followed, that led to the error.

To do so, you must add the following line to your mysqli connection code:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Please see my articles on [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) and [how to report errors in mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting) for more detailed explanation

Answer (score -3):

Does your MariaDB version support prepared statements? The error message basically says that the first question mark is unexpected at that position.

Comment: Im using a local host xampp server and phpmyadmin. It has always worked in the past, but not with this application for some reason.